# Dark theme elevation CSS without using opasity

Tags: css, elevation, darkmode

As described [here](https://material.io/design/color/dark-theme.html#properties) surfaces with different levels of elevation are illuminated differently. And the way to do this is to put an overlay above the surface (according to material design guidlines). I don't know how to do this with pure CSS, so i used this example

```
.dp01 {
    background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 100%, 0.05);
    box-shadow:
        /* offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
        0px 1px 1px 0px hsla(0,0%,0%,0.14), 
        0px 2px 1px -1px hsla(0,0%,0%,0.12), 
        0px 1px 3px 0px hsla(0,0%,0%,0.2);
}

.dp02 {
    background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 100%, 0.07);
    box-shadow:
    /* offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
    0px 2px 2px 0px hsla(0,0%,0%,0.14), 
    0px 3px 1px -2px hsla(0,0%,0%,0.12), 
    0px 1px 5px 0px hsla(0,0%,0%,0.2);
}
```

that plays with opacity. But the opacity based approach has a drawback - if there is some content between or under elevated surfaces it can be seen through the surfaces. So which options i have to implement this?

Comment: Since you are already creating one class per "elevation" why not just set the colour manually?

Comment: I can't set the color manually because elements may be one on top of another. For instance, i may have an elevated surface, then a modal dialog above it which may have a raised button. In this case i'll have to calculate the color somehow instead of setting it manually.